# sort a list which is a Stream Provider but not changing the order of the actual llist

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I need to sort a list

```
final products = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context)
```

I only need to sort it in one screen of more upvotes

```
products.sort((b, a) => a.voteCount.compareTo(b.voteCount));
```

doing this made the whole list sorted and i cannot revert back  to old format
there is two screens trending list and normal list screen if i sort it then both list look the same i need to only the trending screen to be sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another copy of the list, keep in mind that you can't do the following : `List<Product> tmp = products` because `tmp` will reference the same array and this will cause the same issue for you.
Create another array as following : `List<Product> tmp = [...products];`
and then you can call `tmp.sort(...)`.

Comment: List<Product> listbox = products;
    listbox.sort((b, a) => a.voteCount.compareTo(b.voteCount));  I added this and now it changes even the products stream

Comment: i sorted only the tmp but it seem to change the stream list too

Comment: Update your code to check if it is well implemented as i told you.

Comment: thanks man it works properly i didnt see your answer properly at first it is the correct one

Comment: Glad it helped, for more details about this you can read about ```Passing by reference``` and ```Passing by value```